# Error with multiple objects in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I've made a RecyclerView with this tutorial here. All is working fine with **one** object (one line). After adding a second line my layout is completely destroyed and just the first object is shown. Is there someone who knows an answere?

This is one line (All should looks like this line):

[image]

This should be another line like the first one:

[image]

This is my fragment where I create the objects:

```js
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view  =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

    accountRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.account_recycler_view);

    aAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(settingList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager aLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) {
        // Disable scrolling in the RecyclerView
        @Override
        public boolean canScrollVertically() {
            return false;
        }
    };

    // Setup account RecyclerView
    accountRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(aLayoutManager);
    accountRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    accountRecyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);

    prepareAccountData();

    return view;
}

private void prepareAccountData() {
    // Create new setting
    Settings setting = new Settings(1, R.drawable.ic_menu_logout, "Abmelden", "Deine Daten bleibe erhalten");
    // Add Object to list
    settingList.add(setting);

    setting = new Settings(2, R.drawable.ic_menu_logout, "Testadd", "Some text");
    settingList.add(setting);

    // Notify data changes
    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is my adapter:

```js
public class SettingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.MySettingHolder> {

    private List<Settings> settingList;
    private Context context;

    public class MySettingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public int type;
        public ImageView settingImage;
        public TextView settingTitle, settingSubtitle;

        public MySettingHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            settingImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingImage);
            settingTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingTitle);
            settingSubtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.settingSubtitle);
        }
    }

    public SettingsAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SettingsAdapter(List<Settings> settingList) {
        this.settingList = settingList;
    }

    @Override
    public MySettingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.settings_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MySettingHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MySettingHolder holder, int position) {
        // Setting for one entry
        final Settings setting = settingList.get(position);
        //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        holder.settingImage.setImageResource(setting.getSettingImageUrl());
        // If the settingSubtitle is empty it should be not visible and just the settingTitle
        if (setting.getSettingSubtitle().equals("")) {
            //params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
            //holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            //params.setMargins(0, 18, 0, 18);
            //holder.settingTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            //params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 18);
            //holder.settingSubtitle.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder.settingTitle.setText(setting.getSettingTitle());
            holder.settingSubtitle.setText(setting.getSettingSubtitle());
        }

        // Get setting holder type
        holder.type = setting.getType();

        // OnTouchListener for holder/vector color change
        holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // Define setting holder
                MySettingHolder holder = (MySettingHolder) (v.getTag());

                // ImageView for changing color
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.settingImage);

                // Detect if user touch or not
                if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Change ImageView color to primary color
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Change ImageView color to primary color
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(v.getContext(), R.color.iconGray));
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for holder
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                // Define setting holder
                MySettingHolder holder = (MySettingHolder) (v.getTag());

                // Define switch for line
                switch (holder.type) {
                    // Case 1 = Logout
                    case 1:
                        // OnCLickListener for an event
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                switch (which) {

                                    // Case user types Yes
                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                        // Deleting shared preferences for login activity
                                        SharedPreferences loginPreferences = v.getRootView().getContext().getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginPreferences.edit();
                                        editor.clear();
                                        editor.commit();

                                        // Start new acitivity for login
                                        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), LoginActivity.class));

                                        // Exit activity
                                        ((Activity)v.getContext()).finish();

                                        // Exit case button positive/yes
                                        break;

                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                        // Dismiss dialog
                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                        // Exit case button negative/no
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        // AlertDialog for logout check
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getRootView().getContext());
                        builder.setMessage("Möchtest du dich wirklich abmelden?")
                                .setPositiveButton("Ja", dialogClickListener)
                                .setNegativeButton("Nein", dialogClickListener)
                                .show();

                        // Exit switch
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // do other stuff
                        break;

                    default:

                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setTag(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return settingList.size();
    }

}
```

This is my setter/getter:

```js
public class Settings {
    private String settingTitle, settingSubtitle;
    private int settingImageUrl;
    private int type;

    public Settings(int type, int settingImageUrl, String settingTitle, String settingSubtitle) {
        this.type = type;
        this.settingImageUrl = settingImageUrl;
        this.settingTitle = settingTitle;
        this.settingSubtitle = settingSubtitle;
    }

    public void setSettingImage(int settingImageUrl) {
        this.settingImageUrl = settingImageUrl;
    }

    public int getSettingImageUrl() {
        return settingImageUrl;
    }

    public void setSettingTitle(String settingTitle) {
        this.settingTitle = settingTitle;
    }

    public String getSettingTitle() {
        return settingTitle;
    }

    public void setSettingSubtitle(String settingSubtitle) {
        this.settingSubtitle = settingSubtitle;
    }

    public String getSettingSubtitle() {
        return settingSubtitle;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

This is my xml where I define the rows:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Setting icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingImage"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:contentDescription="Icon"
        android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />

    <!-- Setting title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Setting subtitle -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingSubtitle"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingTitle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post settings_list_row.xml too.

Comment: @Saurabh done!!

Comment: try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `Relativelayout` in xml

Comment: @Saurabh What the hell! So easy ;D works like a charm. Please post this as an answer that I can give you a vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the height of the item is `match_parent`. it tries to take whole screen and push other items away.

try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `Relativelayout` in settings_list_row.xml

Comment: Can I ask you something about my OnTouchListener? I think its simple

Comment: sure. go ahead.

Comment: When you look at my adapter you can see a OnTouchListener you can see that I want to change the color of the element I touch. But after having two lines now I can see that I change the color of all elements when I click just one. Is there a way to say #change color for just the clicked item# ?